# Trying to set date through air-date-picker

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add date picker but I am facing issue that Air DatePicker is showing date in both English and One more language I guess Russian 
[image: Here It is Image]

```
//Here it is code I am using for this 
<input required type="text" class="form-control datepicker-here" id="textSchorOfficeOrderDate" autocomplete="off" data-language='en' data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
//And Function for Date
$("#textSchorOfficeOrderDate").datepicker({
            autoClose: true,
            clearButton: true,
            onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
                self.currentDate = date;
//It does't effct if I comment or not below line
                self.onChangeMonthAndYear();
            }
        })
```

I want just English Language Date

Comment: I have added necessary libraries and links already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add language option in your script.I hope it will works for you.

```
$("#textSchorOfficeOrderDate").datepicker({
            autoClose: true,
            clearButton: true,
            language: 'en', //add this line
            onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
                self.currentDate = date;
                //It does't effct if I comment or not below line
                self.onChangeMonthAndYear();
            }
        })
```

This is ref link: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/